# Foursquare venue/search and radius parameter

Tags: ios, api, foursquare

I use [this](https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/search?client_id=5P1OVCFK0CCVCQ5GBBCWRFGUVNX5R4WGKHL2DGJGZ32FDFKT&client_secret=UPZJO0A0XL44IHCD1KQBMAYGCZ45Z03BORJZZJXELPWHPSAR&v=20130117&locale=ru&radius=500&ll=54.94596574654239,73.37603831147895&intent=browse) request to get venues from FS

But distance between some venues and requested location more then 500m. In other words ll and radius parameters doesn't work as I expect. Because I expect to have all venues from requested area.

[image]

It's ok to have 80m inaccuracy. But sometimes I have 600m inaccuracy.

Is it my or foursquare issue? And why it's happen?

btw, i use [Foursquare2](https://github.com/Constantine-Fry/Foursquare-API-v2) to make request.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for bringing this to our attention. This was caused by a little bug in how we return search results and it should be fixed soon.